# regex/php code for replace text between two tags

Tags: php, html, regex, wordpress, replace

I state that I am not a regex expert, but I'm trying to create a code based on some of the examples found here. My need is to replace the string `<li>` with the string `<li class="ingredient">` in a table of WordPress. This change, however, must be done only for text between `[ingredients title = XXXX]` and `[/ingredient]`.

I wrote this PHP code, it works but it removes replace `[ingredients` and `[/ ingredients]`.

Because as I said they are not very expert in the field anybody can help me in changing the code to do what I need?

This is my PHP script:

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("mysql.xxxxxxxxx","xxxxx","xxxxxxxx");
$db =  mysql_select_db ("xxxxxxx");

$sql = "SELECT ID,post_content FROM wp_7pchjn_posts";    

$result = mysql_query($sql);    

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    $id = $row['ID'];
    $search= $row['post_content'];

    if (strpos($search,'[ingredients') !== false) {

        $text = preg_replace_callback("/\[ingredients(.*?)\[\/ingredients\]/ism", function($match) {
          return str_replace("<li>", "<li class=\"ingredient\">", $match[1]);
        }, $search);

        $sql = "UPDATE yourtable set post_content='".$text."' where id='".$id."'";
        mysql_query($sql);
    }
}

mysql_close(); 

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the captured group:

```
(\[ingredients.*?\[\/ingredients\])/ism
```

PHP code:

```
$text = preg_replace_callback("/(\[ingredients.*?\[\/ingredients\])/ism", function($match) {
          return str_replace("<li>", "<li class=\"ingredient\">", $match[1]);
        }, $search);
```